# Difference between `asyncio.wait([asyncio.sleep(5)])` and `asyncio.sleep(5)`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

Could somebody please explain why there is a 5 second delay between `coro2` finishing and `coro1` finishing?

Also, why is there no such delay if I replace `asyncio.wait([asyncio.sleep(5)])` with `asyncio.sleep(5)`?

```
async def coro1():
    logger.info("coro1 start")
    await asyncio.wait([asyncio.sleep(5)])
    logger.info("coro1 finish")

async def coro2():
    logger.info("coro2 start")
    time.sleep(10)
    logger.info("coro2 finish")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(coro1(), coro2())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

```
2020-05-25 12:44:56 coro1 start
2020-05-25 12:44:56 coro2 start
2020-05-25 12:45:06 coro2 finish
2020-05-25 12:45:11 coro1 finish
```

Comment: Don't use ``time.sleep(10)`` in a coroutine. It blocks the entire event loop and all other coroutines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: Do not use blocking calls such as `time.sleep` in a coroutine. Use `asyncio.sleep` to asynchronously pause, or use [an event loop executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) if blocking code must be run.

---

Using `asyncio.wait([thing])` adds a level of indirection, executing `thing` in a new Future/Task. While a bare `await asyncio.sleep(5)` executes the sleep during `coro1`, the wrapped `await asyncio.wait([asyncio.sleep(5)])` executes the sleep *after all* other currently scheduled coroutines.

```
async def coro1():
    logger.info("coro1 start")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)   # started immediately
    logger.info("coro1 finish")

async def coro1():
    logger.info("coro1 start")
    await asyncio.wait([     # started immediately
        asyncio.sleep(5)     # started in new task
    ])
    logger.info("coro1 finish")
```

Since `coro2` uses the blocking `time.sleep(10)`, it disables the event loop and all other coroutines.

```
async def coro2():
    logger.info("coro2 start")
    time.sleep(10)           # nothing happens for 10 seconds
    logger.info("coro2 finish")
```

This prevents further Futures from being started - including new future from `asyncio.wait` - and from being resumed - including the bare `asyncio.sleep(5)`. In the former case, that means the `asyncio.sleep` *starts after* the `time.sleep` is done - therefore taking `10 + 5` seconds to complete. In the latter case, that means the `asyncio.sleep` has already started, it just cannot *complete before* the 10 seconds are up - therefore taking `max(10, 5)` seconds to complete.

---

Consistently use `asyncio.sleep` to get the desired durations. If blocking code must be executed, have it [run via an executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools).

```
async def coro1w():
    print("coro1w start", time.asctime())
    await asyncio.wait([asyncio.sleep(5)])
    print("coro1w finish", time.asctime())

async def coro1b():
    print("coro1b start", time.asctime())
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("coro1b finish", time.asctime())

async def coro2a():
    print("coro2a start", time.asctime())
    await asyncio.sleep(10)            # asynchronous sleep
    print("coro2a finish", time.asctime())

async def coro2t():
    print("coro2t start", time.asctime())
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()  # threaded sleep
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: time.sleep(10))
    print("coro2t finish", time.asctime())

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(coro1w(), coro1b(), coro2a(), coro2t())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I know you shouldn't use `time.sleep` when you could instead use `asyncio.sleep`. I was using it to simulate unavoidable blocking code. Is there any way to avoid the delay whilst still using `time.sleep`?

Comment: All Python async frameworks allow to run blocking code in threads. For asycio, use [``asyncio.loop.run_in_executor``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).