# A blocked Python async function invocation also block another async function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

I use FastAPI to develope data layer APIs accessing SQL Server.
No mater using pytds or pyodbc,
if there is a database transaction caused any request hangs,
all the other requests would be blocked. (even without database operation)

Reproduce:

1. Intentaionally do a serializable SQL Server session, begin a transaction and do not rollback or commit

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[KVStore] VALUES ('1', '1', 0)
    begin tran
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[KVStore]
```

2. Send a request to the API with async handler function like this:

```
    def kv_delete_by_key_2_sql():
            conn = pytds.connect(dsn='192.168.0.1', database=cfg.kvStore_db, user=cfg.kvStore_uid,
                                 password=cfg.kvStore_upwd, port=1435, autocommit=True)
            engine = conn.cursor()
            try:
                sql = "delete KVStore; commit"

                with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                    future = executor.submit(engine.execute, sql)
                    rs = future.result()
                    j = {
                        'success': True,
                        'rowcount': rs.rowcount
                    }
                    return jsonable_encoder(j)
            except Exception as exn:
                j = {
                    'success': False,
                    'reason': exn_handle(exn)
                }
                return jsonable_encoder(j)

    @app.post("/kvStore/delete")
    async def kv_delete(request: Request, type_: Optional[str] = Query(None, max_length=50)):
        request_data = await request.json()

        return kv_delete_by_key_2_sql()
```

3. And send a request to the API of the same app with async handler function like this:

```
    async def hangit0(request: Request, t: int = Query(0)):
        print(t, datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
        await asyncio.sleep(t)
        print(t, datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
        j = {
            'success': True
        }
        return jsonable_encoder(j)
    
    @app.get("/kvStore/hangit/")
    async def hangit(request: Request, t: int = Query(0)):
        return await hangit0(request, t)
```

I expected step.2 would hang and step.3 should directly return after 2 seconds.
However step.3 never return if the transaction doesn't commit or rollback...

How do I make these handler functions work concurrently?

Comment: Please explain better.  The code isn't coherent,  i.e. calls don't match function names

Comment: I updated the function name. The question is even FastAPI use asyncio and I also do wrapping excution in thread pool. The handler in step.2 still blocks handler in step.3. However, step.3 never involves any database operation...

Comment: ``async`` is for *cooperative* concurrency. Using a blocking, regular function is not cooperative. So the trivial answer is "do not use blocking functions". What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between `asyncio.wait([asyncio.sleep(5)])` and `asyncio.sleep(5)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001898/difference-between-asyncio-waitasyncio-sleep5-and-asyncio-sleep5)

Comment: No... it is not related to sleep, I already use asyncio.sleep.
The problem is the database lock caused async function hangs, and another async request is blocked... This is not what I expected...

Comment: In my situation, even the first print in hangit0 doesn't be executed
print(t, datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `rs = future.result()` is actually a blocking call - see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result). Unfortunately, `executor.submit()` doesn't return an awaitable object (`concurrent.futures.Future` is different from `asyncio.Future`.

You can use `asyncio.wrap_future` which takes `concurrent.futures.Future` and returns `asyncio.Future` (see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wrap_future)). The new `Future` object is awaitable thus you can convert your blocking function into an async function.

**An Example**:

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

async def my_async():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future = executor.submit(lambda x: x + 1, 1)
        return await asyncio.wrap_future(future)

print(asyncio.run(my_async()))
```

In your code, simply change the `rs = future.result()` to `rs = await asyncio.wrap_future(future)` and make the whole function `async`. That should do the magic, good luck! :)